# How many weekdays and weekends overlaps in two dates ranges in PHP?

Tags: php, date, datetime, compare, overlap

This function returns how many days two dates ranges overlaps:

```
function datesOverlap($start_one,$end_one,$start_two,$end_two) {

   if($start_one <= $end_two && $end_one >= $start_two) { //If the dates overlap
        return min($end_one,$end_two)->diff(max($start_two,$start_one))->days + 1; //return how many days overlap
   }

   return 0; //Return 0 if there is no overlap
}
```

What I want to know is specifically how many WEEKDAYS and how many WEEKENDS.

What could be the best way in terms of performance?

Comment: Could you provide a test case that shows how you construct the parameters to this function?

Comment: @vallismortis for example:
`$d1=new DateTime("2015-07-01");
$d2=new DateTime("2015-07-08");
$d3=new DateTime("2015-07-05");
$d4=new DateTime("2015-07-18");

echo datesOverlap($d1,$d2,$d3,$d4);`

The result is 4 (days).